# GNU parallel with for loop?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, gnu-parallel

I've found answers close to this but fail to understand how to use them in my case (I'm rather new to Bash)... so, I'm trying to  process a folder containing a large image sequence (100k+ files) with Imagemagick and would like to use GNU Parallel to speed things up.

This is the code I use (processing 100 frames at a time to avoid running out of ram):

```
calcmethod1=mean;
allframes=(*.png)
cd out1

for (( i=0; i < "${#allframes[@]}" ; i+=100 )); do 
    convert "${allframes[@]:i:100}" -evaluate-sequence "$calcmethod1" \
        -channel RGB -normalize ../out2/"${allframes[i]}"
done
```

how would I 'parallelize' this? Most solutions I've found work with not using a loop but piping - but doing this I've run into the problem that my script would break because of my arguments list getting too long...

I guess what I would want to do is to have `parallel` splitting the load like handing the first 100 frames to core 1, frames 100-199 to core 2 etc.?

Comment: Does the order matter when you're calling `convert` with the allframes? The `*.png` gives the glob in a specific order that may not align w/ your intent, if order matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Order

Your sample program did not seem to care about the order of the `*.png` for the `allframes` array that you were constructing, but your comments led me to believe that order would matter.

> I guess what I would want to do is to have parallel splitting the load like handing the first 100 frames to core 1, frames 100-199 to core 2 etc.?

#### Bash

Therefore I'd start with a modification to your script like so, changing the construction of the `allframes` array so that the files are stored in numeric order.

```
allframes=($(printf "%s\n" *.png | sort -V | tr '\n' ' '))
```

This can be simplified further to this using `sort -zV`:

```
allframes=($(printf "%s\0" *.png | sort -zV | tr '\0' ' '))
```

This has the effect on constructing your `convert ...` commands so that they look like this now:

```
$ convert "0.png 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png 9.png \
          10.png 11.png 12.png 13.png 14.png 15.png 16.png 17.png 18.png \
          19.png 20.png 21.png 22.png 23.png 24.png 25.png 26.png 27.png \
          28.png 29.png 30.png 31.png 32.png 33.png 34.png 35.png 36.png \
          37.png 38.png 39.png 40.png 41.png 42.png 43.png 44.png 45.png \
          46.png 47.png 48.png 49.png 50.png 51.png 52.png 53.png 54.png \
          55.png 56.png 57.png 58.png 59.png 60.png 61.png 62.png 63.png \
          64.png 65.png 66.png 67.png 68.png 69.png 70.png 71.png 72.png \
          73.png 74.png 75.png 76.png 77.png 78.png 79.png 80.png 81.png \
          82.png 83.png 84.png 85.png 86.png 87.png 88.png 89.png 90.png \
          91.png 92.png 93.png 94.png 95.png 96.png 97.png 98.png 99.png" \
          -evaluate-sequence "mean" -channel RGB -normalize ../out2/0.png
```

#### Parallels

Building off of eschwartz's example I put together a `parallel` example as follows:

```
$ printf '%s\n' *.png | sort -V | parallel -n100 --dryrun convert {} \
   -evaluate-sequence 'mean' -channel RGB -normalize ../out2/{1}
```

again, more simply using `sort -zV`:

```
$ printf '%s\0' *.png | sort -zV | parallel -0 -n100 --dryrun "convert {} \
   -evaluate-sequence 'mean' -channel RGB -normalize ../out2/{1}
```

**NOTE:** The above has an echo "..." as the `parallel` action to start. Doing it this way helps to visualize what's happening:

```
$ convert 0.png 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png 9.png 10.png \
         11.png 12.png 13.png 14.png 15.png 16.png 17.png 18.png 19.png \
         20.png 21.png 22.png 23.png 24.png 25.png 26.png 27.png 28.png \
         29.png 30.png 31.png 32.png 33.png 34.png 35.png 36.png 37.png \
         38.png 39.png 40.png 41.png 42.png 43.png 44.png 45.png 46.png \
         47.png 48.png 49.png 50.png 51.png 52.png 53.png 54.png 55.png \ 
         56.png 57.png 58.png 59.png 60.png 61.png 62.png 63.png 64.png \ 
         65.png 66.png 67.png 68.png 69.png 70.png 71.png 72.png 73.png \ 
         74.png 75.png 76.png 77.png 78.png 79.png 80.png 81.png 82.png \
         83.png 84.png 85.png 86.png 87.png 88.png 89.png 90.png 91.png \
         92.png 93.png 94.png 95.png 96.png 97.png 98.png 99.png \
         -evaluate-sequence mean -channel RGB -normalize ../out2/0.png
```

If you're satisfied with this output, simply remove the `--dryrun` switch to `parallel`, and rerun it.

```
$ printf '%s\0' *.png | sort -zV | parallel -0 -n100 convert {} \ 
    -evaluate-sequence 'mean' -channel RGB -normalize
```

#### References

- [[Published in Open Source For You (OSFY) magazine, October 2013 edition.]](http://www.shakthimaan.com/posts/2014/11/27/gnu-parallel/news.html)

Comment: that does do the trick and is exactly, what i was looking for! thank you and eschwartz so much!!! interestingly, parallel does not speed up the process much when using all (8) threads, the best performance i get with using only two threads (`parallel -j 2`)... which does boost speed almost to the double though! i'm a happy camper now...

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is to print the filenames using a shell builtin like `printf '%s\0' *.png` which is not vulnerable to the ARG_MAX limitation on command-line argument length, and then pipe it to `parallel --null` which will read those filenames and batch the jobs however you wish.

Some features of `parallel` which we will use:

- `--null` is required to sanely split filenames on null characters to prevent weird issues with weird filenames
- `-n 100` will, just like xargs, handle 100 files for each invocation
- `{}` contains those 100 filenames
- `../out2/{1}` contains just the first one

So, this would become:

```
calcmethod1=mean
printf '%s\0' *.png | parallel --null -n 100 convert {} -evaluate-sequence $calcmethod1 -channel RGB -normalize {} ../out2/{1}
```

Why do you think piping would not work? Piping works fine, it is only externally forked commands that do *not* read from a pipe, which have issues with *argument length*. Piping is in fact the whole purpose of `parallel`.

Comment: thank you for your help!!! after some reading i do have a vague idea of what you are suggesting... but you would not happen to have some code illustrating this, would you? i manage to build this argument with xargs like this `ls *.png | xargs -n 100 sh -c 'convert "$0" "$@" -evaluate-sequence $calcmethod1 ../out2/"$0"'` (which produces the arg_max problem though) but how would i translate this to something starting with parallel --null?!?

Comment: `ls` is not a shell builtin, it is an externally forked command and therefore you get ARG_MAX errors from `ls` before the pipeline ever takes effect. Also relevant: [don't use ls in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) since it is a tool meant **only** for interactive use.

Comment: um, i'm afraid this doesn't work in this case. it processes the images individually - whereas i need to hand the convert process 100 images at a time to composite these together - this is what the `xargs -n 100` is for and what i do not manage to translate into parallel...

Comment: `parallel` will default to one job per CPU core, that is why there is the `--jobs N` option, so I guess `parallel --null --jobs 100 convert ...` would do the trick... this is described in the manpage though.

Comment: This determines the number of processes spawned but does not get me anywhere closer, I'm afraid. Every time I execute this convert command, I need to hand it the next 100 files in my list - this is one operation. So what i need parallel to do is something like "convert these 100 pngs here using the first thread, the next 100 pngs on the second thread, etc."... In any case: Thank you so much for helping me with this!!!

Comment: I didn't know convert processed multiple images in one process... However it seems mogrify does. `mogrify -path ../outdir *.png`

Comment: mogrify can't do what i need to do. i'm not converting single images but calculating the temporal mean/median/whatever of image sequences, something like this: https://patdavid.net/2013/09/mean-averaging-music-videos.html

Comment: Hmm. Okay, luckily `parallel` lets you parameterize the first filename again, and it too supports `-n`. Not sure what having `convert` do multiple files gets you other than less forking though, since it's still being distributed across all cores either way.

Comment: sims's answer below does what i need (built upon your example), again mr. eschwarz: thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to run every `convert` process in its own subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=1; i<=1000; i++ )) do
(
command --options ) &
disown
done

exit 0
```

To see how it works, try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hi!"

for (( i=1; i<=1000; i++ )) do
(
sleep 30
echo "Bye, "$i"!" ) &
disown
done

exit 0
```

Assign to the script name `par.sh` and check processes afterwards:

```
ps aux | grep par.sh
```

We can assume native Linux CPU load balancer should spread processes between CPU cores evenly since every subshell has a separated pid. Anyway, something like `cpuset` is always available to be used.

Comment: thanks for your solution bob! i tried your approach and it certainly does spread the operation in different processes - only would it spawn a process for each individual image, freezing up... i guess for a skilled person (= not me), it's probably easy to build these processes in batches of 100 as outlined by slm but i did not test this...